# Javascript inner couldn't find property closure

Tags: javascript

```
var init = function( selector ){

        this.element = $(selector);

        var foo = function(){
            console.log(this.element);  
        };

        foo();
};
```

I have a inner function try to access property `this.element`, but it couldn't find it.

why couldn't access closure, anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: Second `this` refers to `foo()` funciton

Comment: this function actually in prototype, so if I set var self = this; in parent, prototype will not able to get var self

Comment: Are you added with jquery link ? `$` is jquery

Comment: should I put var self = this in prototype function?

Comment: This is Javascript 101. The `this` keyword has been explained by so many people so often that if you find one explanation unsatisfactory you can go on and pick the next until you find one that makes it click.